# yii2 mongodb - add comments to existing field how to

Tags: php, mongodb, yii2

I have a collection called work-monitor where-in I have two fields namely 
`assignor_remarks` and `assignee_remarks`.

so when a comment is submitted by either assignor or assignee, I want to add those comments in the respective comment filed.
I am able to save the comments in the collection, but new comments is overriding the existing one.

my code is like this:

```
public function actionWorkUpdate($id)
      {
        \Yii::$app->request->enableCsrfValidation = false;
        $work = $this->modelClass::find()->where(['_id'=>$id])->one();

        $work->load(Yii::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParams(), '');

        $work->assignee_remarks = ["timestamp"=>date('d-m-Y h:i'),"comments"=>$work->assignee_remarks];
    $work->update();
    return "success";
  }
```

how I can achieve this.

update like in the example below:

```
"assignee_remarks":{"comment":"test comment","commentTime":2020-04-29 12.41},
{"comment":"test comment2","commentTime":2020-04-29 12.45},
{"comment":"test comment3","commentTime":2020-04-29 12.50}
```

Comment: Maybe I have understood you wrong. Do you have multiple field assignee_remarks? So assignee_remarks should be an array? Maybe it's not. And when you load data you set assignee_remarks from bodyParams and then write it into db, only new data, don't you? In this case, save previous data before load and then add new data to it?

Comment: No, assignee_remarks is a single field. see my update in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that, if I have understood you correctly.

```
// In Work Model

public $assignee_remarks;

public function rules()
{
    return [
        //...
        ['assignee_remarks', 'safe'] // for free load
    ];
}

// In controller

/**
 * In bodyParams you have new comment like assignee_remarks: 'some text'
 * @param $id
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionWorkUpdate($id)
{
    \Yii::$app->request->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    $work = $this->modelClass::find()->where(['_id' => $id])->one();

    $currentComments = $work->assignee_remarks ?? [];
    $work->load(Yii::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParams(), '');

    $currentComments[] = ["commentTime" => date('d-m-Y h:i'), "comment" => $work->assignee_remarks];
    $work->assignee_remarks = $currentComments;

    $result = $work->update();

    if ($result === false) {
        // validation error
    } else {
        return $result > 0 ? 'success' : 'fail';
    }
}
```